# What is correct, "...as much as we are" or "...as much as us"?

Tags: word-choice

I recently came across the sentence -

"Comment on this post if you are as thankful for the bees as much as **us**."

Would it be, "Comment on this post if you are as thankful for the bees as much as **we are**."?

Comment: These both mean different things. If you are using "us" then this literally means that "you" are equally grateful for "the bees" and "us." "Comment on this post if you are as thankful for the bees as (you are for) us." The "we" version is probably the intended meaning.

Comment: Both are ungrammatical, to start with. There should be no _as much_ in the second part. Simple _as ... as_ is the conjunction. So you're asking about _if you're as thankful for the bees as us_ vs _if you're as thankful for the bees as we are_. Probly the latter is better than the former; but inbetween there's a third option, often taken: _if you're as thankful for the bees as we_. Potential ambiguity is not really an issue with a standard construction like this.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would never say *if you're as thankful for the bees as we* and if I heard it then I would wait for the verb which needs to follow *we*